# Given a potential function, can one directly write down the induced metric tensor on the level sets?

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a potential function $V:\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ within an appropriate class of differential function, one can define its level sets to be:
$$
\Sigma_{V}^{v}:=\{X:=\{x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\} \; |\; V(X)=v \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\}.\qquad (1)
$$

Being $\Sigma_{V}^{v}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we introduce the Euclidean metric tensor:
$$
g:=\delta_{ij}\;dx^{i}\otimes dx^{i}, \qquad (2)
$$
and compute the induced metric tensor on such a hypersurface that we denote with $g_{\Sigma_{V}^{v}}$.

In so doing, one can rewrite the Euclidean metric (by means of the coarea formula, for instance) as follows:
$$
g=\frac{de\otimes de}{\|\nabla V\|^{2}}+g_{\Sigma_{V}^{e}},\qquad (3)
$$
where $\nabla$ is the gradient of the function $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, namely, $\nabla:=\{\partial_{x_{1}},\ldots,\partial_{x_{n}}\}^{T}$.

I am interested in explicitly computing the expression for $g$ in Eq. (3), having only $V(X)=v$.
For the first term on the right-hand side of Eq. (3), this can be easily done, however, for the second term is not clear to me.

In particular, I did not understand whether the calculation of $g_{\Sigma_{V}^{v}}$ requires that I introduce a curvilinear system of coordinates on $\Sigma_{V}^{v}$ or it is enough to have an explicit expression for $f(X)=e$.

Therefore, I am searching for any explicit procedure (independent by the dimension and possibly by the expression $V(X)=v$) which allows to write down the induced metric tensor on the hypersurface $\Sigma_{V}^{v}$.

I could provide an explicit mathematical expression that defines a level set, that is:
$$
V(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}):=\sum_{I=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x_{i}^{2}}{4}\right).
$$

How does the induced metric tensor $g_{\Sigma_{V}^{v}}$ look like?

Comment: $$g_{\Sigma} = g - \frac{(dV)^2}{|dV|^2}$$

Comment: Elegant. Would you share a reference please? I’m learning something new, thank you @Deane!

Comment: Actually my formula isn’t helpful at all. If you restrict it to $\Sigma$, the second term vanishes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for really makes sense. As a simpler but ultimately equivalent situation, take a linear subspace $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. What does it mean to "write down" the restriction of the dot product from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $S$? In the same vein, expression $(3)$ doesn't make sense as written: $g$ and $g_\Sigma$ are bilinear forms on different vector spaces. If you fix a coordinate chart on the level set, however, then it makes sense to ask how to write $g_\Sigma$ *in that chart*.

Comment: Dear @Kajelad, there is a similar question that has been posed here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578131/how-to-compute-the-metric-tensor-for-a-surface-defined-by-an-equation/3578189

However, in that case, the procedure used only works in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, I actually was wondering if there is something similar in a general n-dimensional Euclidean space. Clearly, if I had a coordinate chart everything would be clear. My question was: can I get the projection on $\Sigma_{V}^{v}$ just having $V(X)=v$?

Comment: @LLOR The answer you linked *is* using a coordinate chart, specifically the local graph coordinates $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,z(x,y))$. I'm not sure what you mean by "the projection".

Comment: @Kajelad, I would say that I am in the same setting of the question in the link: I have a map $(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})\mapsto (x_{1},\ldots,x_{n},V(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}))$ (see the example that I proposed). The point is I would like to understand if I can write a metric tensor on a hypersurface embedded in a $n$-dimensional Euclidean space (in particular a level set) having only the relation above. Furthermore, I never used the nomenclature "projection" but induced metric tensor that I think it is a well-defined object. Finally, I proposed a possible way to do that but maybe it is not the only one.

Comment: Au contraire. The method used in the answer you linked works in any number of dimensions. Implicit differentiation is quite general.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks for your comment. Hence, I wonder whether there is a connection between the result obtained there and the induced metric tensor that I wrote, i.e., $g_{\Sigma(V)}^{v}$.

Comment: You haven’t written anything concrete or specific. You’re just saying that abstractly we can split the metric into two orthogonal pieces. Now what? To calculate you need (local) coordinates, as the previous answer proceeds to do.

Comment: I agree that, in general, for dealing with manifold and writing down a metric tensor, one should introduce a system of coordinates. However, I would say that my question is, for sure, more concrete than the one posed in the link. Moreover, I did not see any coordinate chart in the link. To the contrary, I just saw an implicit equation like here (only that I provided an example here). As you said, if I can use the same approach (and in that approach, any coordinates has been introduced) I do not understand why I should introduce coordinates in my case.